# Multiple content types in a library causes metadata problems on file upload

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-set, metadata

I defined Document Set content type “A” (Engineering) to contain custom site metadata (for simplicity, call them 1, 2 and 3). I defined Document Set content type “B” (Energy Services) to contain custom site metadata (call them 4, 5 and 6). *My custom metadata uses "lib." prefix for clarity*.

[image: Engineering content type (content type "A")]

[image: Energy Services content type (content type "B"]

I created a document library and configured it to include instances of A and B along with default content types Document, Image, Video and a couple more.

[image: Doc Set A created from Content Type A]

[image: Doc Set B created from Content Type B]

[image: Library properties showing Document Sets A and B included]

When I am in Document Set A and upload a document, the metadata assignment screen shows me 1-3 as I expect, but it also shows 4-6 which do not apply to A;

[image: Doc Set A asks for metadata from Doc Set B]

likewise, when I am in B and upload a document, the assignment screen shows me 1-3 (which I do not want) along with 4-6.

[image: Doc Set B upload asking for Doc Set A metadata]

I cannot figure out how to restrict the metadata entry screen to just those columns defined within the content type.

If it’s relevant, I had another issue to solve: As shown in the Library Settings window, the default content types were not automatically “Used in” the document sets created from A and B even though I included the default types within A and B. As such, 1-6 were not appearing in the metadata assignment screen upon upload. So, in Library Settings I selected a default type (eg, “Document”) and manually added my custom site metadata 1-6 and that cured the issue. I don’t think it’s related to my existing issue, but thought I would mention it just in case.

It’s easy to get lost in the language...I hope this made sense.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add some screenshots of what you're experiencing.

Comment: Oops, noob here and I don't see an obvious way to upload images.

Comment: Figured out adding screen captures.

Comment: Still hoping someone can point me in the right direction...